# Extending an existing element class in Android

Tags: android

Lets say I want to extend an e,element calls in Android, For example the Button element.
So I have this class:

```
Class MyButton extends Button{
     ...

}
```

So when I want to use this element I should in the layout xml file put:

```
<MyButton/>
```

or

```
<Button>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the fully qualified classname, so:

```
<my.application.package.MyButton>
```

And make sure that your class is `public`.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it like this here:

```
<you.package.MyButton>
```

Note that you need to implement the both constructors with the xml attributes else this won't work:

```
//Constructor that is called when inflating a view from XML.
View(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)

//Perform inflation from XML and apply a class-specific base style.
Vew(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should check this site for lots more on custom views:
http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

You'll need to use the full classpath in this case, but you should check that reference for a lot more information on a custom view.